# Moving controls from TabPage to Panel; controls being skipped

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

So everyone knows a very popular way to display settings now is to have a ListView on the left with options that changes a Panel on the right, when clicked.

Several years ago, I came across one way to easily manage this is to create a TabControl, put the controls for each settings category in the tab page during design time, because it makes it easy to switch tabs and edit the pages.

During run time, when the settings page is opened, you create Panels for each TabPage, move the controls from the TabPage to its corresponding panel and add the Text (title) of each TabPage into the ListView on the left.  And then, if you want, you can destroy the TabControl to free up memory.

The problem I am having is that as my code iterates through the controls on a TabPage, it won't add some of them.  In my case, they are all CheckBoxes at the moment, so I'm confused as to why some would not be moved.  During debug, I can check TabPage.Controls and all CheckBoxes are there, but as it iterates, it just doesn't add some of the controls to the Panel.

I have an image of how I have this setup during DesignTime, what it looks like at RunTime, and what my code is that is handling the move from TabPages to Panels.

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening?  I'm stumped.

DesignTime: http://postimg.org/image/h6ssw1chp/

RunTime: http://postimg.org/image/4i7f6uv05/

```
public void setPanels()
{
    foreach (TabPage tab in tabSettingGroups.TabPages)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel()
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            Visible = true
        };

        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(tab.Text)
        {
            Tag = panel
        };
        lvwOptions.Items.Add(lvi);

        foreach (Control ctrl in tab.Controls)
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
    }

    //Destroy TabControl to free up memory
    tabSettingGroups.Dispose();
}
```

If you would like to recreate everything, you need at least a SplitContainer, with the ListView in SplitContainer.Panel1 and the TabControl in SplitContainer.Panel2.

As you can see, I have added each built Panel that was created for each TabPage directly into the Tag property of the ListViewItem.  When the ListViewItem is clicked, SplitContainer.Panel2 is emptied and the Panel from ListViewItem.Tag is added to SplitContainer.Panel2

```
private void lvwOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pnlSettings.Panel1.Controls.Clear();
    Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Item.Tag;
    pnlSettings.Panel1.Controls.Add(pnl);
}
```

NOTE: I added a second SplitContainer to house the TabControl and the Save/Cancel buttons so that the buttons were inline with the Parent SplitContainer so that I didn't create even more unused "whitespace" to the left of the buttons.  In the _Click method above, just do .Panel2 (basically, the same Panel that you put the TabControl).

Comment: My guess is that they are there but not in your currently showing view area.  I would not suggest this approach for swapping user display data.  Creating UserControls that contain all of the "panel" data then loading that panel into the area would be better.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not following 100%.  How exactly do you mean?

Comment: Also, Brian, I checked the panel.Controls, and only 3 of the 5 are there.  They definitely didn't make it into the Panel's list of Controls.

Comment: He means, create a custom UserControl for each group of setting controls.  (Eg.  A user control which contains a panel which itself contains all related controls.)  Then add that User control to the tab panel when it's needed.  Dynamic forms are great but sometimes, the simple approach is all you really need to get the job done.

Comment: @JamesShaw So the idea would be to then get that UserControl from the TabPage instead of trying to move controls around, I just move that whole Panel, and since it's a UserControl, I know everything will go with it?

Wouldn't a problem with that be though, that I don't have direct access to the CheckBox Names to assign my settings to them?

I could just add the Panel as a Panel (not using a UserControl), and just move the whole Panel around (same concept), but then I still get access to the CheckBox controls in code, directly.

Comment: @RobertBurke Sure you do.  If you create a custom Control that extends or implements a UserControl object. You simply add public properties within that newly created custom UserControl to manipulate the control values and private properties within the panel that it contains.

Comment: @JamesShaw Yeah, duh...lol  My bad.  (Haven't used UserControls that much)

Comment: Please do not add the items to a tabcontrol then remove them.  You can actually build all of this so that in designer you can see the exact same display as the running app, all using CustomControls.

Comment: @RobertBurke One of the main advantages of the suggested approach would be keeping related data, objects and controls specific to a task or setting organized and encapsulated within a class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection is changing while you iterate them, so a simple trick is to go in reverse:

```
for (int i = tab.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  panel.Controls.Add(tab.Controls[i]);
}
```

or the one-liner:

```
panel.Controls.AddRange(tab.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToArray());
```

As other users have commented, probably better to just house each view in a separate UserControl instead of trying to move these controls — it will lead to spaghetti code trying to manage all those changes.

Comment: Ahh, I get it.  Because I'm moving items off the stack and then the new number references every other control because everything has moved up one.  Bah.

Comment: Exactly what @LarsTech said.  It will inevitably lead to spaghetti code over time and reiteration. This can quickly become hard to troubleshoot. Weigh the pros and cons. Pro, you gain a dynamically generated list of settings. Cons may outweigh... :)

Comment: While I will be changing my method of handling everything (per suggestions above), this is technically the answer to the question.